# Stringbuilder to 2D array Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, stringbuilder

I am doing a school project and I'm having a bit of trouble transforming a Stringbuilder into a 2D array.

The stringbuilder sb contains a 2D matrix, which I want to convert into a 2D int.

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

This is the matrix I have in the sb that I want to convert into an int[][].

Any ideas?

Comment: you answered your own question. school project.... just start using those grey cells of urs

Comment: if I am asking here probably it's something we have to do by searching the web, and not taught in class.

Comment: then search the web, you are asking a question here.

Comment: You need [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (explanations are in the code)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //assuming the stringbuilder has the contents below (each line ending in space followed by a newline character)
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 \n");
    sb.append("1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n");
    sb.append("1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 \n");
    sb.append("1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 \n");
    sb.append("0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 \n");
    sb.append("0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 \n");
    sb.append("0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 \n");
    sb.append("0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 \n");

    //extract each line from the sb by splitting after the newline character \n
    final String[] rows = sb.toString().split("\n");
    //each line represent a row, so the numbers of lines is the number of rows in our matrix
    final int totalRows = rows.length;
    //the lenght of each line, if we replace space with nothing, represents the number of columns
    //columns have the same number of elements for each line so we can read it from the first row, row[0]. it will be the same for all the others 
    final int totalColumns = rows[0].replace(" ", "").length();
    //create matrix with proper size
    final int[][] matrix = new int[totalRows][totalColumns];

    //initialize first row index
    int currentRow = 0;
    //initialize first column index
    int currentColumn = 0;

    for (String row : rows) { //for each row
        row = row.substring(0, row.length() - 1); //remove last space character
        final String[] elements = row.split(" "); //store each element of the row in an array by splitting after the space character
        for (final String element : elements) { //for each element
            //add element in matrix at correct position
            matrix[currentRow][currentColumn] = Integer.parseInt(element); //convert string to int
            //increment column count for the next element
            currentColumn++;
        }
        //increment row count for the next row
        currentRow++;
        //reset column counter for the next row
        currentColumn = 0;
    }

    //display the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++) {
            if (j == 7) {
                //if last column add a newline after the element
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\r\n"); // where \r\n = CarriageReturn + LineFeed and is used as a new line character in Windows
                //or simply replace the above line with System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
            } else {
                //if not last column add just a space after the element
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting mix of `\n` and `\r\n`. And you know that the method `System.out.println()` exists? Or use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29).

Comment: @Tom since op is dealing with newlines in the sb i thought it would be clearer from him when displaying the matrix to use the same. and since it's a school project i doubt their teacher is looking for a one method solution.

Comment: This doesn't describe the usage of `\r\n`, but ok. Everyone should use "Windows style" :D.

Comment: @Tom ok I edited it, you are right, I should have explained it

Comment: I guess it would be easier to use `println` instead, so you don't have to deal with the different line ending types.